# How to make flowplayer detect video resolution change on the fly?

Tags: javascript, video, web, flowplayer

I have a rtmp video stream which is dynamically changing it's resolution and aspect ratio during the process of streaming and i wish to somehow play it on a web page.

For this purpose i have chosen a flowplayer solution, but it is not detecting video aspect ratio change during the process of streaming, though does that perfectly when flowplayer initially loaded and fetched video the first time (e.g. after reload of web-page with flowplayer on it). I wish to enable it do dynamically detect aspect ratio of the stream, changing it on-the-fly.

How it is possible?

I have tried different flowplayer' clip' scaling options, but they are affecting only the initial loading stage and constant all the time later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Had to do the following thing in clip definition, now clip is resizing properly:

```
clip: {
    onMetaDataChange: function(clip) {
      clip.update({scaling: 'fit'});
    },
    ... rest of the options ...
}
```